# Props are changed but ComponentDidUpdate not called

Tags: reactjs

I have an alert / messages system that utilizes redux to trigger a alert component to render. However im encountering an issue whereby the props have changed but yet the `componentDidUpdate` method did not run. Here's my code:

**App.js**

```
const alertOptions = {
  timeout: 4000,
  position: 'top center',
  offset: '10px',
};

const AlertTemplate = ({ style, options, message }) => (
  <Alert
  style= {style}
  message={options.type}
  description={message}
  type={options.type}
  showIcon
  closable
/>)


class App extends Component {
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.autoCheckState();
    }

  render() {    
    if (this.props.loading['authentication'] === true) {
        return <Spin size="large" />
    } else {
        return (
          <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate}{...alertOptions}>
          <Router>
            <Alerts/>
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Main}/>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            </Switch>
          </Router>
          </AlertProvider>
        )

      }
  }
}
  
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    autoCheckState: () => dispatch({ type: 'CHECK_AUTH'})
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.loading.loading,
});


    
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**Alert.js (Component)**

```
class Alerts extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log('HELOOOOOOOO') //<--- Log to see if this life cycle method is running
    const { error, alert, message } = this.props;
    if (error !== prevProps.error && error) {
      if (error.detail) {
        if (error.detail === "Given token not valid for any token type") {
          alert.error('Your session has ended , please reverify your credentials')
        } else {
          alert.error(error.detail)
        }
      }
      if (error.name) alert.error(error.name);
      if (error.email) alert.error(error.email);
      if (error.message) alert.error(error.message);
      if (error.new_password) alert.error(error.new_password);
      if (error.old_password) alert.error(error.old_password);
      if (error.non_field_errors) alert.error(error.non_field_errors);
      if (error.username) alert.error(error.username);
      if (error.custom) alert.error(error.custom);
    }
    if (message !== prevProps.message  && message) {
      alert.success(message)
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.error)   //<---- log to show that the props have changed.
    return <Fragment />;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  error: state.messages.error,
  message: state.messages.message,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withAlert()(Alerts));
```

To replicate the issue , I have purposely entered the wrong user credentials into my `login` page. The `alert.js` component will log the following:

**Before entering any credentials**

```
null
```

**After keying in the wrong credentials**

```
{detail: "No active account found with the given credentials"}
```

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` doesn't run on initial render, what are you updating to try and trigger it?

Comment: @RedBaron im updating the state.messages.error to try to triger an alert . In my redux it shows that the props does indeed change , however componentDidUpdate was not called

Comment: why do you need `componentDidUpdate`, it's probably because there was no change in the virtual dom

Comment: Because if when there's an error from within my server in validating the request , i will send back an error response to be stored as an error object in my state. Thus the componentDidUpdate will then be triggered theoretically to render the error message.

Comment: if there's an error from a request, just set it straight to state (and render the state)? no need for this lifecycle method